# Read from text file and save word frequency to new text file printing each on a new line

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-files, frequency

Good day. Help needed please. Language used is python. The code below reads from a text file and then returns frequency of each word each on a new line. I got it from this site  https://rmtheis.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/count-word-frequency-with-python/

```
import re
from collections import Counter


def openfile(filename):
    fh = open(filename, "r+")
    str = fh.read()
    fh.close()
    return str


def removegarbage(str):
    # Replace one or more non-word (non-alphanumeric) chars with a space
    str = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', str)
    str = str.lower()
    return str


def getwordbins(words):
    cnt = Counter()
    for word in words:
        cnt[word] += 1
    return cnt


def main(filename, topwords):
    txt = openfile(filename)
    txt = removegarbage(txt)
    words = txt.split(' ')
    bins = getwordbins(words)
    for key, value in bins.most_common(topwords):

        print(key, value)

main('hamlet.txt', 500)
```

From the above, it prints fine on the IDE i'm using (pyCharm). But when i add the following code just below the code above,

```
#Write to file
    with open("newFile.txt", "w") as f:
        for word in main('hamlet.txt', 500):
            f.write(word + os.linesep)
```

it does print on the **console** fine but **shows some errors**, also it **did not write to the text file** which i created at all. .Below is a snippet showing sample output on the console after reading a text file, it prints:

```
the 16
of 12
to 9
search 9
which 6
```

So now, i want to write this above output to a text file.The content of the textile is much longer than the above though. Thank you. By the way, the error got on the console is

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/test/PycharmProjects/Trial/trial.py", line 52, in <module>
    for word in main("hamlet.txt", 500):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use the function `main` as shown, i.e.,

```
for word in main('hamlet.txt', 500):
```

then the function should be adapted for this.
One could use for example a generator:

```
def main(filename, topwords):
    txt = openfile(filename)
    txt = removegarbage(txt)
    words = txt.split(' ')
    bins = getwordbins(words)
    for key, value in bins.most_common(topwords):
        # yield key #generate only the word, not it's frequency
        yield key, value

with open("newFile.txt", "w") as f:
    for word, freq in main('hamlet.txt', 500):
        f.write('%s\t%d\n' % (word, freq))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried as you advised. It did save to a textile but it does not show frequency. But like i stated earlier, the results has to be saved in a text file and also the frequency as well. Just like the  sample output i showed above. So please how can you help me here? Thanks again...

Comment: @user3761841 in that case, the generator can yield both values. These are then written into the output file. I have update the answer accordingly.

Comment: 'And that did the trick....wow, thanks a lot. Python seems a bit weird though.. I'm from a java background... Thankssss a lot..'

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return key, value` instead of printing it

Comment: Thank you of the response.I followed as you instructed, i didn't change anything other than changing from (return key, value) to (return key, value), but i seems not to even run at all this time. It shows an error.

Comment: Something about TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and        'str'

Comment: I tried it just as you instructed. It saved to a textile but only one word was saved and shows no frequency likewise. What can I do now please? Thank you.